# A bag of numbers in C++ for constant time statistics queries

Tags: c++, statistics

(See the [next](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161774/a-bag-of-numbers-in-c-for-constant-time-statistics-queries-follow-up) iteration.)

I have this simple "data structure" for storing numbers and querying the statistics on them (average, variance and standard deviation):

**numberbag.hpp**

```
#ifndef CODERODDE_STAT_NUMBER_BAG
#define CODERODDE_STAT_NUMBER_BAG

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

namespace coderodde {

    namespace stat {

template<typename Num = long double>
class number_bag {

    size_t m_size;
    Num    m_sum;
    Num    m_square_sum;

public:
    number_bag() : m_size{0}, m_sum{0}, m_square_sum{0} {}

    void add(Num num) {
        m_size++;
        m_sum += num;
        m_square_sum += num * num;
    }

    void remove(Num num) {
        m_size--;
        m_sum -= num;
        m_square_sum -= num * num;
    }

    void clear() {
        m_size = 0;
        m_sum = 0;
        m_square_sum = 0;
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return m_size;
    }

    Num ave() const {
        return m_sum / m_size;
    }

    Num var() const {
        Num step1 = m_square_sum - m_sum * m_sum / m_size;
        return step1 / (m_size - 1);
    }

    Num std() const {
        return sqrt(var());
    }
};

template<typename Num>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, number_bag<Num> const &bag)
{
    out << "[size=" << bag.size() << ", ave=" << bag.ave() << ", var="
        << bag.var() << ", std=" << bag.std() << "]";
    return out;
}

    } // end of namespace coderodde::stat

} // end of namespace coderodde

#endif // CODERODDE_STAT_NUMBER_BAG
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "numberbag.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    using coderodde::stat::number_bag;
    using namespace std;

    number_bag<> bag;
    bag.add(1.0);
    bag.add(1.0);
    bag.add(3.0);

    cout << bag << "\n";

    bag.remove(1.0);

    cout << bag << "\n";

    bag.clear();

    cout << bag << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**Demo output**

> ```
> [size=3, ave=1.66667, var=1.33333, std=1.1547]
> [size=2, ave=2, var=2, std=1.41421]
> [size=0, ave=nan, var=nan, std=nan]
> ```

**Critique request**

Please tell me anything that comes to mind. Especially, I am not sure that putting the output override (`operator<<`) in the namespace is OK.

Comment: Putting the operator<< overload in the namespace is exactly what you want. That way it is found by ADL (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup) and doesn't pollute the global namespace..

Comment: In case you're not aware of it, this is similar to (a subset of) the Boost [Accumulators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/accumulators.html) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the code is not doing a rocket science, I'll only mention subtle things that slipped through.

**Non-associative math:**

Floating point math is very dangerous to deal with. This is especially true when optimizations are all high (I actually had to observe it myself). So, the expression:

```
m_sum * m_sum / m_size;
```

has chances to produce different results on different optimization levels. It is better to put parentheses:

```
(m_sum * m_sum) / m_size;
```

**Calling non explicit constructor:**

```
    m_size = 0;
    m_sum = 0;
    m_square_sum = 0;
```

Those statements might not compile if the constructor of `Num` is `explicit`. I think sometimes it is reasonable to make it `explicit`. Instead, directly call the constructor with the `0` in it:

```
    m_size = Num(0);
    //ditto
```

**Non-portable code:**

```
return sqrt(var());
```

Unqualified call assumes that `sqrt()` is present in the current namespace. It is not always so, since `cmath` guarantees only functions being available in `std` namespace.

**Unnecessary include:**

`<cstdlib>` looks useless here. `<cstddef>` should be used instead for `std::size_t`.

**cosmetics:**

`Num` is too generic. `FloatingPoint` would do better, though the class can use fixed point as well. If I would know word for combination of both, I would put it instead of `Num`. It will tell more about the type.

Indentations inside of namespaces is weird for me.

**Design:**

May be it would be possible to write something like in a python:

```
bag - num(12);
```

so it would remove the number from bag. The current design seems slightly verbose.

**ADL:**

As mentioned in the comment, it is good to put the operator inside of the namespace **in which the class appears**, and in namespaces that `inline`d into namespace that declares the class. It will trigger argument dependent lookup, the reason why `using std::swap; swap(a, b);` works.

Comment: Very nice and helpful review. Thank you! Could you, however, elaborate **Excess assumptions**? I am not quite clear about the syntax.

Comment: @coderodde, thanks! Just use `Num(0);`, i.e. directly call value constructor. Sorry for being a little brash there.

Comment: @coderodde, I believe [the link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) about `explicit` keyword should support my point.

Comment: I will take a look but later.

Comment: This phenomenon is called non-_associative_ math.

Comment: @vnp, thanks, fixed. It is really hard for me to remember which one is what.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question. The link is a the top of this page.

Comment: @coderodde, already digging into it :)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is your public function names.  It would make it more user friendly if they were more verbose(average,variance,standard)

Comment: I posted a follow-up question. The link is a the top of this page.