# A bag of numbers in C++ for constant time statistics queries - follow-up 2

Tags: c++, statistics

(See the [2nd/previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161774/a-bag-of-numbers-in-c-for-constant-time-statistics-queries-follow-up) iteration.)

I essentially removed all the type conversion trickery and have this:

**numberbag.hpp**

```
#ifndef CODERODDE_STAT_NUMBER_BAG
#define CODERODDE_STAT_NUMBER_BAG

#include <cmath>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

namespace coderodde {
namespace stat {

template<typename FloatingPoint = long double>
class number_bag final {

    size_t        m_size = 0;
    FloatingPoint m_sum{};
    FloatingPoint m_square_sum{};

public:

    number_bag() = default;

    number_bag(const number_bag& other) :
        m_size{other.m_size},
        m_sum{other.m_sum},
        m_square_sum{other.m_square_sum}
    {}

    number_bag& operator=(const number_bag& other) {
        m_size = other.m_size;
        m_sum = other.m_sum;
        m_square_sum = other.m_square_sum;
        return *this;
    }

    number_bag(number_bag&& other) :
        m_size{other.m_size},
        m_sum{std::move(other.m_sum)},
        m_square_sum{std::move(other.m_square_sum)}
    {}

    number_bag& operator=(number_bag&& other) {
        m_size = other.m_size;
        m_sum = std::move(other.m_sum);
        m_square_sum = std::move(other.m_square_sum);
        return *this;
    }

    number_bag(std::initializer_list<FloatingPoint> init_lst) {
        for (auto fp : init_lst) {
            add(fp);
        }
    }

    void add(FloatingPoint num) noexcept {
        ++m_size;
        m_sum += num;
        m_square_sum += num * num;
    }

    void remove(FloatingPoint num) noexcept {
        --m_size;
        m_sum -= num;
        m_square_sum -= num * num;
    }

    void clear() noexcept {
        m_size = 0;
        m_sum = FloatingPoint{};
        m_square_sum = FloatingPoint{};
    }

    size_t size() const noexcept {
        return m_size;
    }

    FloatingPoint average() const noexcept {
        return m_sum / m_size;
    }

    FloatingPoint variance() const noexcept {
        FloatingPoint step1 = m_square_sum - (m_sum * m_sum) / m_size;
        return step1 / (m_size - 1);
    }

    FloatingPoint standard_deviation() const noexcept {
        return std::sqrt(variance());
    }

    number_bag operator+(FloatingPoint fp) const noexcept {
        number_bag ret(*this);
        ret.add(fp);
        return ret;
    }

    number_bag operator-(FloatingPoint fp) const noexcept {
        number_bag ret(*this);
        ret.remove(fp);
        return ret;
    }

    number_bag& operator+=(FloatingPoint num) noexcept {
        add(num);
        return *this;
    }

    number_bag& operator-=(FloatingPoint num) noexcept {
        remove(num);
        return *this;
    }
};

template<typename FloatingPoint>
auto operator+(FloatingPoint fp, number_bag<FloatingPoint>& bag) noexcept {
    number_bag<FloatingPoint> ret(bag);
    ret.add(fp);
    return ret;
}

template<typename FloatingPoint>
auto operator-(FloatingPoint fp, number_bag<FloatingPoint>& bag) noexcept {
    number_bag<FloatingPoint> ret(bag);
    ret.remove(fp);
    return ret;
}

template<typename Num>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, number_bag<Num> const &bag)
{
    out << "[size=" << bag.size() << ", ave=" << bag.average() << ", var="
        << bag.variance() << ", std=" << bag.standard_deviation() << "]";
    return out;
}

} // end of namespace coderodde::stat
} // end of namespace coderodde

#endif // CODERODDE_STAT_NUMBER_BAG
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "numberbag.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using coderodde::stat::number_bag;
    using namespace std;

    number_bag<float> bag;

    bag.add(1.0);
    bag.add(1.0);
    bag.add(3.0);

    cout << "bag:  " << bag << '\n';

    auto bag2 = bag - 1.0l;

    cout << "bag:  " << bag << '\n';
    cout << "bag2: " << bag2 << '\n';

    auto bag3 = 1.0f + bag2;

    cout << "bag3: " << bag3 << '\n';

    bag.clear();

    cout << "bag:  " << bag << '\n';

    bag += 2.0f;
    bag += 7.0f;

    cout << "bag:  " << bag << '\n';

    bag2 = {1, 1, 3.0};
    cout << "bag2: " << bag2 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**Critique request**

Please tell me about anything there is to improve.

Comment: You still have the numerical precision problem I described in [my answer to the previous iteration](/a/161828).  Consider using Knuth's method instead, such as in [this answer](//math.stackexchange.com/a/116344).

Comment: @TobySpeight I just have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: Also, from Math Overflow, [Numerically most robust way to compute sum of products (standard deviation) in floating-point?](//mathoverflow.net/q/70345) and from The Mindful Programmer, [Welford’s method for computing variance](http://jonisalonen.com/2013/deriving-welfords-method-for-computing-variance/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why do you re-implement the default copy and move constructors and assignments? Just let the compiler generate them for you.
2. Mark `operator<<` as `noexcept`. `main` too if you wish, although not required, as if `main` throws an exception, the program terminates no matter what.
3. You may omit the `return 0;` in `main`, the compiler will add one for you if you omit it.
4. To avoid copies, use `auto&&` instead of `auto`:

   ```
   for (auto&& fp : init_lst) {
       add(fp);
   }
   ```
5. With C++17, you would be able to check if `operator+` on `FloatingPoint` will throw or not with the [`std::is_nothrow_invocable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable#firstHeading) type trait. That will enable you to enable or disable `noexcept` on functions that call `operator+`.

   In the mean time, you can either leave them `noexcept`, which means that any `FloatingPoint::operator+` can't throw, or remove it, to let users add a throwing `operator+`. The same goes for any functions/operators that you're either not sure about, or want to require the type to not throw.
6. You could add some comparison operators to compare `number_bag` objects.

Comment: Point 1. Will it be sufficient to declare all 5 as `= default`?

Comment: Hmm. It did actually.

Comment: @coderodde Well, yes. But you can remove them (except for the default constructors if course), as they are not implicitly deleted.

Comment: Also, default move constructor moves everything to move, whereas the default copy constructor copies every field?

Comment: @coderodde Exactly

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks! My wording is indeed very unclear :)

Comment: Your English is much better than my German, so don't be over-modest!

Answer (score 2):

## Consider adding an insert iterator

You don't know how this class is going to be used, but there's a good chance that somebody will want to populate it using one of the standard algorithms, such as `std::transform` or `std::copy`.

You can make that easier to do by providing a suitable iterator.  A simple way to do so is to write `push_back()` (and possibly also `push_front()` and `insert()`).  With such a method, `std::back_inserter()` can be used; it will to return a `std::back_insert_iterator<number_bag>`, which will call your `push_back()` as needed, without requiring any further work on your part.

```
void push_back(const FloatingPoint& value) noexcept
{
    add(value);
}
```

Alternatively, just rename `add()` - you might then want to change `remove()` to `pop_back()`.

Answer (score 2):

While you might just want to use the default move constructor and move assignment, you should mark them `noexcept` Otherwise the compiler needs to wrap those with exception handling code.

Comment: Nice one! Never thought about what difference `noexcept` has. Keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 0):

Your code suffers from he numerical precision problem I described in [my answer to the previous iteration](/a/161828).  To avoid this, we can store the current mean and *n* times the current variance, and use [Welford's method](http://jonisalonen.com/2013/deriving-welfords-method-for-computing-variance/) to update these when numbers are added to the bag.

Here's an outline of this approach:

```
#include <limits>

template<typename T>
    requires std::numeric_limits<T>::has_quiet_NaN
class SimpleStatsBag
{
    static constexpr auto nan = std::numeric_limits<T>::quiet_NaN();

    std::size_t count = 0;
    value_type current_mean = 0;
    variance_type current_nvar = 0;     // count times the current variance

public:

    // Accessors for the statistical properties
    std::size_t size() const { return count; }

    T mean() const { return count ? current_mean : nan; }

    T population_variance() const { return count ? current_nvar / count : nan; }
    T sample_variance() const { return count > 1 ? population_variance() * count / (count - 1) : nan; }


    // Mutators - add and remove values
    void insert(value_type value)
    {
        auto const old_mean = current_mean;
        current_mean += (value - current_mean) / ++count;
        current_nvar += (value - current_mean) * (value - old_mean);
    }

    void remove(value_type value)
    {
        auto const old_mean = current_mean;
        if (count) {
            current_mean -= (value - current_mean) / --count;
            current_nvar -= (value - current_mean) * (value - old_mean);
        }
    }
};
```

(I've used Concepts to constrain the template above; just remove the `requires` line if your compiler doesn't support that yet).